# PHP - Define file include in class for all methods to use

Tags: php, class, methods

Is there a way on including a file at the beginning of a class for all methods to use. The example below is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve. Currently I have to include the file within every method.

Example Logic (not working)

```
    class Myclass
    {
        protected require_once 'folerd1/folder2/pear/HTTP/Request2.php'; // this does not work

        public function aMethod()
        {
            $request = new HTTP_Request2('http://example1.com/', HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
            try {
                $response = $request->send();
                if (200 == $response->getStatus()) {
                    echo $response->getBody();
                } else {
                    echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
                        $response->getReasonPhrase();
                }
            } catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function aMethod1()
        {
            $request = new HTTP_Request2('http://example2.com/', HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
            try {
                $response = $request->send();
                if (200 == $response->getStatus()) {
                    echo $response->getBody();
                } else {
                    echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
                        $response->getReasonPhrase();
                }
            } catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        // more methods
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried requiring it in the constructor?

Comment: The constructor will assign a value to a variable. I'm not sure on how to do something like this within a construct method. I've never came across it before.

Comment: I'm no guru at all, but cant you call require_once("folerd1/folder2/pear/HTTP/Request2.php"); on the constructor? It would load any variables and I presume you would be able to use them inside the entire class.

Comment: Is there a reason to set the require to protected?

Comment: @TIMINeutron I just tried your suggestion. Thanks in does in fact work. Could you put this as answer and I will mark it as correct. That way it will help out others also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 solution

1) require_once taken outside from class

```
require_once 'folerd1/folder2/pear/HTTP/Request2.php';     
class Myclass
{
```

2) Include in the construct

```
public function __construct() {
    require_once 'folerd1/folder2/pear/HTTP/Request2.php';
}
```

But it is better first option

Comment: yep, sorry - without protected!

Comment: The second solution done the job. I done this based on advice from @TIMINeutron

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to look at autoloading  standard http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

Have you tried this? I don't know what's your Request2.php file content. So my code is only a PoC!

```
require 'folerd1/folder2/pear/HTTP/Request2.php'; 

class Myclass
{
    public function aMethod()
    {
        $request = new Request2('http://example1.com/', Request2::METHOD_GET);
        try {
            $response = $request->send();
            if (200 == $response->getStatus()) {
                echo $response->getBody();
            } else {
                echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
                    $response->getReasonPhrase();
            }
        } catch (Request2_Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function aMethod1()
    {
        $request = new Request2('http://example2.com/', Request2::METHOD_GET);
        try {
            $response = $request->send();
            if (200 == $response->getStatus()) {
                echo $response->getBody();
            } else {
                echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
                    $response->getReasonPhrase();
            }
        } catch (Request2_Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented out, just require the file in the constructor of the PHP class:

```
class Myclass{
    function Myclass(){
        require_once('folerd1/folder2/pear/HTTP/Request2.php');
    }
```

I have not checked this, but it MIGHT be possible that what you're just doing is including it not only for all the class to see, but the entire script. Please, check that out if it is a problem for you. If not, the other 2 solutions might end up doing the same.

Cheers